# What does Block queued job plugin do in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

The queue job in Jenkins gets automatically started when the current job gets finished/aborted. Which is the normal behaviour. I found a plugin called "[Block queued job plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin)" which also does the same thing.
It block the queue of a project unless the running job of the project gets finished.

Then Whats the use of "Block queued job plugin"?? I want to use it if it solves the following problem:
A build flow has a restart slave machine step in it .Example:

```
build( "RestartMachine" , MachineName: "ctttest-06" )
build( "CheckForShutdown")
build( "RunTest" )
```

In case there is an ongoing build flow and another build flow is in queue. Whenever the the job executes "RestartMachine". The queued job starts executing and takes over  the slave which not expected as the ongoing job was not finished.